# JSON Get Value by Edittext

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get JSON value by EditText.

At first I had a bunch of nullpointer exceptions, solved that. But now my function just isn't working. Been wrapping my brain over this...

I tried to create a EditText, get that value to a String, and get it over to the JSON Object. Don't know what I'm doing wrong... Or am I forgetting something?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView uid;
    TextView name1;
    TextView email1;
    EditText edt;
    Button Btngetdata;

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "*";
    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_TAG = "tag";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "country";

    JSONArray user = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONParse().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
            name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
            email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TAG);
                JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);



                String xyz = edt.getText().toString();
                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_LAST_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                //Set JSON Data in TextView
                uid.setText(id);
                name1.setText(name);
                email1.setText(email);
                edt.setText(xyz);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

> {"tag":[{"id":"1","first_name":"Philip","last_name":"Porter","email":"pporter0@admin.ch","country":"China","ip_address":"26.83.255.206"},{"id":"2","first_name":"Nancy","last_name":"Martin","email":"nmartin1@google.ca","country":"Colombia","ip_address":"160.93.80.1"},{"id":"3","first_name":"Ann","last_name":"Peterson","email":"apeterson2@utexas.edu","country":"China","ip_address":"251.254.74.162"},{"id":"4","first_name":"Rachel","last_name":"Clark","email":"rclark3@mayoclinic.com","country":"Brazil","ip_address":"58.218.248.5"},{"id":"5","first_name":"Heather","last_name":"Burton","email":"hburton4@creativecommons.org","country":"Ethiopia","ip_address":"244.69.119.16"},{"id":"6","first_name":"Ruth","last_name":"Lane","email":"rlane5@va.gov","country":"Brazil","ip_address":"18.173.102.54"},{"id":"7","first_name":"Andrew","last_name":"Turner","email":"aturner6@devhub.com","country":"United States","ip_address":"13.119.240.234"},{"id":"8","first_name":"Wanda","last_name":"Medina","email":"wmedina7@pagesperso-orange.fr","country":"Netherlands","ip_address":"151.139.21.237"},{"id":"9","first_name":"Robert","last_name":"Elliott","email":"relliott8@joomla.org","country":"United States","ip_address":"34.200.249.109"},{"id":"10","first_name":"Kevin","last_name":"Harrison","email":"kharrison9@nih.gov","country":"Brazil","ip_address":"106.84.164.86"}]}

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT

---

```
    JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(xyz));
```

I Modified to this, im getting a response other than default 1 when base value was getJSONObject(0), but now im entering 1 and im getting 2, entering 4 getting 5..

Does anyone know how to solve this one?

Comment: could you post tour json? maybe you are not getting the right values, as for the views the seem ok

Comment: i just added the json

Comment: uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
            name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
            email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);

move this to oncreate

Comment: can u show `getJSONFromUrl(url)` method

Comment: @George, this still selects only the first id.

Comment: @kaushik i have added the json parser. getJSONFromUrl is included.

Comment: Try using this: c.optString(TAG_EMAIL);

Comment: @AmolTate Do you mean to change the getString action? Replacing it does not work

Comment: Yes just try to change getString() to optString()

Comment: if you are trying to parse the whole id into a list then check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

For a particular position try like this

```
int positionToShow = Integer.parseInt(edt.getText().toString()) - 1;
user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TAG);
for(int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
   if(positionToShow == i) {
       JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(i);
       // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
       String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
       String name = c.getString(TAG_LAST_NAME);
       String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
       uid.setText(id);
       name1.setText(name);
       email1.setText(email);
   }       
}
```

Comment: put a `System.out.print(String.valueOf(list.size()))` at the end outside `for` *loop*. If it has a value `>` 0 then u have every value u want.

Comment: Where should i put it? behind list.add?

Comment: after `list.add` outside of `for` *loop* or u can place a `Toast` msg.

Comment: This didnt do anything.

Comment: what is the value in `Log cat`

Comment: I have changed JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(xyz)); but now it automatically selects a +1 value.. 

SO if i enter 2, i get 3.. how do i make it return 2?

Comment: It doesnt help, since it still returns +1 value

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse the whole json array then use this.In you post execute

```
List<String> allid = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray obj= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("tag");
for (int i=0; i<obj.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject actor = cast.getJSONObject(i);
    String id= actor.getString("id");
    allNames.add(id);
}
```

Then you can use a for loop to get the id in the list accordingly.

Otherwise you can do this parsing Using the Gson Library(you can download Gson library [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip&)
Just create a class in your package

```
public class DetailArray {
    public boolean status;
    public List<Detail_User> details;

    public class Detail_User {
        public String id;
        public String first_name;
        public String last_name;
        public String email;
        public String country;
    }
}
```

In your post execute

Where response is the json response

```
DetailArray detail1 = (new Gson()).fromJson(response.toString(),
                DetailArray.class);
```

Now Suppose , if you want to set the names in a list view then

```
//return a arraylist
private ArrayList<String> getName(DetailArray detail) {
    ArrayList name = new ArrayList<String>();

      for (int i=0;i< detail.details.size();i++) {
        name.add(splitStr[i]);
       }
    return names;
}
```

Setting the array adapter and setting it to a list

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                     this, 
                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                     getName(detail);
      listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

> i've parse your json ...acc to number entered ..and it shows exact result....refer this....

```
    final EditText no=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final Button click=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            try
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, no.getText().toString(), 0).show();
                HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request=new HttpGet("http://192.168.0.30/test.js");
                HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);

                HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                String json=EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject j1=new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray ja1=j1.getJSONArray("tag");
                JSONObject j2=ja1.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(no.getText().toString())-1);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, j2.getString("first_name").toString() , 0).show();

                entity.consumeContent();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.getStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString()  , 0).show();
            }
        }
    });
```